# Can I accept two funded offers from universities and decide later after April 15?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding

I am an international student. I received several offers, but I am interested in two options:

1) Option A: It is my top choice. However, it gave me only partial tuition, so I will need external sources of funding. The resolution of these sources is going to be in June (federal funds), several months after the April 15th deadline. 
2) Option B: It gave full tuition and a monthly living stipend. I am very grateful to the university.

For both programs, I have until April 15 to accept offers. I have been reading about April 15 Resolution and it has complicated me to make a decision. Since both schools gave me financial aid, I think there is a problem in there about accepting an offer concerning financial aid. As far as I understand, in Option A, if I pay my deposit fee I accept their financial aid. Nevertheless, to attend Option A I will necessarily need external funding. If I don't receive it, I will not be able to attend Option A.

I already have an opportunity to study a graduate program in US (Option B). I would not like to be in the scenario of rejecting a good and safe opportunity and not have external funding, that would mean not to attend graduate studies this year. I would love to go to Option A, but I am restricted to external factors as funding.

Is there any advise you could give me in this situation?

Comment: Some students take a break or intermit to top-up their funds with a job...

Answer (score 5):

**No, you cannot do this.**

According to the [April 15 Resolution of the Council of Graduate Schools](http://cgsnet.org/april-15-resolution), you cannot accept multiple award offers simultaneously. You are not committed to any offer signed before April 15, in that you can submit a written statement declining a previously accepted offer. But you cannot accept multiple offers before or on April 15, and changing offers after that date requires a written release from the school with whom the offer that was “in force” on April 15.

Comment: So, there are only two options: 1) accept safe offer or 2) life is about risks. Right?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: Question is, how are they going to know? Following some dumb rule for the sake of following dumb rules is dumb.